# click event listener not stiking . Vanila js

Tags: javascript, dom, filter

I've created a store with a list of products that are generated from js and i attached an event listener to every product.
For sorting purposes, i've decided to recreate the dom to put the products in the order that i want but the problem is that the click event doesnt work and i dont know why. My line of thinking is that if something is declared globally, it should be accesable from all corners of the aplication. Am i right?

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
//arr of products
const productsArr = [{
    name: 'Aname1',
    price: 200
  },
  {
    name: 'Cname2',
    price: 2000
  },
  {
    name: 'Zname3',
    price: 28
  },
  {
    name: 'Pname4',
    price: 5
    
  }

];
const paintProducts = function() {
  productsArr.forEach(product, () => {
    let price = product.price;
    let name = product.name;
    //create html
    productsHtml = `<div  product data-price="${price}"   data-name = "${name}">
     <h6 class="price">${price} coco</h6>
      <p class="product-descr">${description}</p>
      </div>`
  });
  //insert html
  grid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', productsHtml);
};
paintProducts();
// filter
const aZBtn = document.querySelector('.a-z');

const filterAlphabetically = () => {
  allInstruments.sort(function(i, j) {
    if (i.name < j.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (i.name > j.name) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
};
//clean the dom
const cleanGrid = function() {
  grid.innerHTML = '';
};

aZBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  filterAlphabetically();
  cleanGrid();
  paintProducts();
  clickOnProduct();
});
const products = document.querySelectorAll(".product")
const clickOnProduct = function() {
  products.forEach(function(product) {
      product.addEventListener('click', () => {
          console.log("something here")
        
      })
  })
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="a-z">Alphabetically</div>
  <div class="grid">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I found a logical flaw in `paintProducts`

The following line was outside the loop, so only 1 item could ever be rendered, the last one.
`grid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', productsHtml);`

Second was in `filterAlphabetically`. There a mistery variable pops up `allInstruments`, replaced it with `productsArr`.

Third problem was `const products = document.querySelectorAll(".product")`. This was outside the `clickOnProduct` function.
As every repaint generates new DOM elements, after sorting, the events need to be bound to the new elements.

Fourth problem is the product div itself, it countained `<div product ...`  but you are using a queryselector referring a class so this should be `<div  class="product"  ...`

When fixing all the above, we result in this:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="a-z">Alphabetically</div>
    <div class="grid">
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  <script>
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
//arr of products
const productsArr = [{
    name: 'Aname1',
    price: 200
  },
  {
    name: 'Cname2',
    price: 2000
  },
  {
    name: 'Zname3',
    price: 28
  },
  {
    name: 'Pname4',
    price: 5
    
  }

];
const paintProducts = function() {
  productsArr.forEach(product => {
    let price = product.price;
    let name = product.name;
    //create html
    productsHtml = `<div  class="product" data-price="${price}"   data-name = "${name}">
     <h6 class="price">${price} coco</h6>
      <p class="product-descr">${name}</p>
      </div>`
      
    //insert html
    grid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', productsHtml);
  });
};
paintProducts();

// filter
const aZBtn = document.querySelector('.a-z');

const filterAlphabetically = () => {
  productsArr.sort(function(i, j) {
    if (i.name < j.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (i.name > j.name) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
};

//clean the dom
const cleanGrid = function() {
  grid.innerHTML = '';
};

aZBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  filterAlphabetically();
  cleanGrid();
  paintProducts();
  clickOnProduct();
});

const clickOnProduct = function() {
  var products = document.querySelectorAll(".product")
  products.forEach(function(product) {
      product.addEventListener('click', () => {
          console.log("something here")
        
      });
  });
}  
 clickOnProduct()
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: ok. most of my mistakes were because i rewritten the code to simplify it and i did it in a rushed way. but the third problem that you found, omg. i never thought of that. thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Have fun.